# ¿Cómo inicializo cada elemento del arreglo de estructuras?

Tags: c

Quiero crear un arreglo de estructuras e inicializar cada elemento del arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
struct A *a = (struct A*)malloc(3*sizeof(struct A));
    a[0] = {1, 3,{"Manzana\n", "Pera\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"} };
    a[1] = {2, 4,{"Mango\n", "Limón\n", "Papaya\n", "Uva\n"} };
    a[2] = {5, 3,{"Tamarindo\n", "Lima\n", "Jícama\n", "Sandía\n"} };
```

Al compilar sucede esto:
[image: LMINT]

Aquí está el programa completo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char ingredientes[10][30];
};

    int main(void){
    
        struct A *a = (struct A*)malloc(3*sizeof(struct A));
        a[0] = {1, 3,{"Manzana\n", "Pera\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"} };
        a[1] = {2, 4,{"Mango\n", "Limón\n", "Papaya\n", "Uva\n"} };
        a[2] = {5, 3,{"Tamarindo\n", "Lima\n", "Jícama\n", "Sandía\n"} };
        
        //Imprime los 4 ingredientes.
        for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
            printf(a[0].ingredientes[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[0]` es un puntero que se inicializa con un puntero a algo. Hay un inicializador de estructura, pero ¿Qué estructura es? Hay que decirlo usando la sintaxis para *literal compuesto*

```
a[0] = (struct A) {1, 3, {"Manzana\n", "Pera\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"} };
```

Un literal compuesto construye un objeto sin nombre del tipo específicado. Se usa cuando se requiere un arreglo, estructura o
unión por una sola vez.

El programa queda así:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char ingredientes[10][30];
};

    int main(void){
    
        struct A *a = (struct A*)malloc(3*sizeof(struct A));
        a[0] = (struct A) {1, 3, {"Manzana\n", "Pera\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"} };
        a[1] = (struct A) {2, 4, {"Mango\n", "Limón\n", "Papaya\n", "Uva\n"} };
        a[2] = (struct A) {5, 3, {"Tamarindo\n", "Lima\n", "Jícama\n", "Sandía\n"} };
        
        //Imprime los 4 ingredientes.
        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Ingredientes[%d]\n", j);
            for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
                printf(a[j].ingredientes[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

produce:

```
Ingredientes[0]
Manzana
Pera
Guayaba
Fresa
Ingredientes[1]
Mango
Limón
Papaya
Uva
Ingredientes[2]
Tamarindo
Lima
Jícama
Sandía
```

Comment: `(struct A){ ... }` no es un cast, es un [literal compuesto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), aun asi es una forma interesante de inicializar la estructura a la que apunta el puntero devuelto por malloc

Comment: @braver. Edite la pregunta para incluir tu aclaración.